# Get Number of Failed Active Directory Log in Attempts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory, membership-provider

Here is how I get the number of failed AD log in attempts in my old webforms log in app:

[Authentication.cs]

```
var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "blahnet.blahad.com", "dc=blahnet,dc=blahad,dc=org");
bool validated = pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
var ADElement = IdentityType.SamAccountName;
var up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, ADElement, username);
int numberOfFailedLoginAttempts = up.BadLogonCount;
```

And here is what I have so far for authentication in my new MVC 5 login app.

[web.config]

```
    <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="SamAccountName" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://blahnet.blahad.com:389/DC=blahnet,DC=blahad,DC=com" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

[AccountController.cs]

```
bool validated = Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

With this new method, how can I get the number of failed AD log in attempts like above?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Membership` class is generic. To get that AD specific property of an account, my guess is you will still have to use `UserPrincipal` instance of the account.  BTW, if possible you can also use a product like Manage Engine's Auditing: http://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/